# Maintaining Population Size in a Genetic Algorithm/Program

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm writing genetic program, but it's been a while so I'm a little rusty.

If I start with a population size of 100 individuals, and select 50 through tournament selection for reproduction, and after crossover each pair produces 50 next-generation individuals, I'm left with 100 1st-gen individuals (which will no longer reproduce, no longer part of the "population") and 50 current-gen individuals. So my tournament selection of 50 won't really work. Should the tournament selected individuals also go on to the next generation? Or should they reproduce 2:1 somehow?

Thanks for the refresher!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to perform selection and crossover in a Genetic Algorithm but generally, if you're using tournament selection you're best to select as many individuals as your population and have them produce the same number of offspring.

There are a number of ways to produce the same number of offspring as parents but, as an example, if performing a straight forward one point crossover each half of the initial parent would carry forward with the other half of the other parent. That way two parents produce two offspring. For example

```
Parent 1: 00000000
Parent 2: 11111111
```

With a crossover point after the third bit.

```
Offspring 1: 00011111
Offspring 2: 11100000
```

Afterwards you can discard your entire initial population and replace them with all the offspring.

Note: This doesn't take into account any specialised operator you may want to include which can help to carry the best individuals forward every population. But that's another story....

Comment: Got it! So the idea is the tournament selection will randomly select pairs of individuals, the best one of the two going forward to crossover, but there can be multiple copies of the same individual in the crossover group (if it was chosen multiple times)?

Comment: Depending on the relative fitness of your individuals in tournament selection you'll often see multiple copies of the best individuals in the crossover population. Since it's likely that they will a) crossover with different individuals than each other and/or b) crossover at different points this is usually a good idea. It encourages diversity while allowing for the best individuals to have more prevalence in the next generation.

Comment: Usually, there isn't actually a physical crossover group. You'll perform selection twice, perform crossover to generate offspring, and repeat the process until you have the required number of offspring. Genetic algorithms can vary hugely so you won't always crossover in a 1:1 ratio. I've seen GA's where two parents are selected from a population of 1,000 to create one offspring. This process is carried out 1,000 times to create 1,000 offspring. If the two selected individuals produced two offspring the process would be carried out 500 times. It really depends on preference/requirements

Comment: This make sense only if you're looking for a single solution for a problem. If you are looking for multiple solutions, then you're looking for multiple species ( that is how I think it should), which by definition are genetically separated (cannot mate with other species), if GA is a 1:1 model of the evolution theory then it should be like that. otherwise it is far from it. Multiple solutions shouldn't be modeled as  multiple individuals of the same specie. But I guess GA is modeling a single population looking for a single solution.

Comment: @OnABauer thank you for your answer, that was a big missing f****** piece of the puzzle :)